# Centos "cannot create temp file for here-document: Read-only file system"

Tags: centos, readonly, cpanel

I am getting this error what ever I want to do on my server

```
cannot create temp file for here-document: Read-only file system
```

cpanel, whm and all websites are Down

All my system files are read-only. I search for anything that might help
but it is not working :(

I have 200G of free disk space.
My OS is Centos with WHM (Cpanel)
It is on the Hetzner data center
Rescue did not help

I cannot edit /etc/fstab because it is read-only.

```
vim /etc/fstab
```

my disks are

```
[root@server ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs         32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs            32G   25M   32G   1% /run
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md2        874G  545G  285G  66% /
tmpfs           6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/0
```

I tried to remount, but it does not work either.

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

output of 'dmesg | tail'

```
[    3.576436] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s31f6: link is not ready
[    6.969821] e1000e: enp0s31f6 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
[    6.970035] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp0s31f6: link becomes ready
[   10.124036] ip6_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[   10.140747] nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (65536 buckets, 262144 max)
[   42.683041] systemd-readahead[566]: Failed to open pack file: Read-only file system
[   60.065749] ip_set: protocol 7
[  302.063222] EXT4-fs (md2): error count since last fsck: 354
[  302.063288] EXT4-fs (md2): initial error at time 1622194023: ext4_xattr_block_get:321: inode 37361099
[  302.063461] EXT4-fs (md2): last error at time 1660967530: ext4_xattr_block_get:321: inode 37358850
```

output of 'journalctl -xe'

```
[root@server ~]# journalctl -xe
Jan 20 19:31:31 server.mm.com rsyslogd[1205]: action 'action 1' suspended, next retry is Fri Jan 20 19:32:01 2023 [v8.24.0-57.el7_9.3 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Jan 20 19:31:31 server.mm.com rsyslogd[1205]: imjournal: fopen() failed for path: '/var/lib/rsyslog/imjournal.state.tmp': Read-only file system [v8.24.0-57.el7_9.3 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2013 ]
Jan 20 19:31:31 server.mm.com PAM-hulk[5183]: failed to connect stream socket
Jan 20 19:31:31 server.mm.com sshd[5183]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Jan 20 19:31:31 server.mm.com sshd[5183]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=46.101.248.68
Jan 20 19:31:31 server.mm.com rsyslogd[1205]: imjournal: fopen() failed for path: '/var/lib/rsyslog/imjournal.state.tmp': Read-only file system [v8.24.0-57.el7_9.3 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2013 ]
Jan 20 19:31:31 server.mm.com rsyslogd[1205]: imjournal: fopen() failed for path: '/var/lib/rsyslog/imjournal.state.tmp': Read-only file system [v8.24.0-57.el7_9.3 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2013 ]
Jan 20 19:31:32 server.mm.com sshd[5183]: Failed password for invalid user amssys from 46.101.248.68 port 38188 ssh2
Jan 20 19:31:32 server.mm.com sshd[5183]: Received disconnect from 46.101.248.68 port 38188:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jan 20 19:31:32 server.mm.com sshd[5183]: Disconnected from 46.101.248.68 port 38188 [preauth]
Jan 20 19:31:33 server.mm.com PAM-hulk[5182]: failed to connect stream socket
Jan 20 19:31:33 server.mm.com sshd[5182]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=61.177.173.39  user=root
Jan 20 19:31:33 server.mm.com sshd[5182]: pam_succeed_if(sshd:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "root"
Jan 20 19:31:33 server.mm.com rsyslogd[1205]: imjournal: fopen() failed for path: '/var/lib/rsyslog/imjournal.state.tmp': Read-only file system [v8.24.0-57.el7_9.3 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2013 ]
Jan 20 19:31:34 server.mm.com sshd[5189]: Invalid user netadmin from 43.134.40.99 port 42568
Jan 20 19:31:34 server.mm.com sshd[5189]: input_userauth_request: invalid user netadmin [preauth]
Jan 20 19:31:34 server.mm.com PAM-hulk[5189]: failed to connect stream socket
Jan 20 19:31:34 server.mm.com sshd[5189]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Jan 20 19:31:34 server.mm.com sshd[5189]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=43.134.40.99
Jan 20 19:31:35 server.mm.com sshd[5182]: Failed password for root from 61.177.173.39 port 58331 ssh2
Jan 20 19:31:36 server.mm.com PAM-hulk[5182]: failed to connect stream socket
Jan 20 19:31:36 server.mm.com sshd[5182]: pam_succeed_if(sshd:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "root"
Jan 20 19:31:37 server.mm.com sshd[5189]: Failed password for invalid user netadmin from 43.134.40.99 port 42568 ssh2
Jan 20 19:31:37 server.mm.com rsyslogd[1205]: imjournal: fopen() failed for path: '/var/lib/rsyslog/imjournal.state.tmp': Read-only file system [v8.24.0-57.el7_9.3 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2013 ]
Jan 20 19:31:37 server.mm.com sshd[5189]: Received disconnect from 43.134.40.99 port 42568:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jan 20 19:31:37 server.mm.com sshd[5189]: Disconnected from 43.134.40.99 port 42568 [preauth]
Jan 20 19:31:38 server.mm.com sshd[5182]: Failed password for root from 61.177.173.39 port 58331 ssh2
Jan 20 19:31:38 server.mm.com PAM-hulk[5182]: failed to connect stream socket
Jan 20 19:31:38 server.mm.com sshd[5182]: pam_succeed_if(sshd:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "root"
Jan 20 19:34:36 server.mm.com rsyslogd[1205]: file '/var/log/messages': open error: Read-only file system [v8.24.0-57.el7_9.3 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2433 ]
Jan 20 19:34:36 server.mm.com systemd[1]: Started clamd antivirus daemon.
-- Subject: Unit clamd.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit clamd.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Jan 20 19:34:36 server.mm.com rsyslogd[1205]: action 'action 0' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.24.0-57.el7_9.3 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Jan 20 19:34:36 server.mm.com rsyslogd[1205]: file '/var/log/messages': open error: Read-only file system [v8.24.0-57.el7_9.3 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2433 ]
Jan 20 19:34:36 server.mm.com rsyslogd[1205]: action 'action 0' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.24.0-57.el7_9.3 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Jan 20 19:34:36 server.mm.com rsyslogd[1205]: file '/var/log/messages': open error: Read-only file system [v8.24.0-57.el7_9.3 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2433 ]
Jan 20 19:34:36 server.mm.com rsyslogd[1205]: action 'action 0' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.24.0-57.el7_9.3 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Jan 20 19:34:36 server.mm.com rsyslogd[1205]: file '/var/log/messages': open error: Read-only file system [v8.24.0-57.el7_9.3 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2433 ]
Jan 20 19:34:36 server.mm.com rsyslogd[1205]: action 'action 0' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.24.0-57.el7_9.3 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Jan 20 19:34:36 server.mm.com rsyslogd[1205]: file '/var/log/messages': open error: Read-only file system [v8.24.0-57.el7_9.3 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2433 ]
Jan 20 19:34:36 server.mm.com rsyslogd[1205]: action 'action 0' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.24.0-57.el7_9.3 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Jan 20 19:34:36 server.mm.com rsyslogd[1205]: file '/var/log/messages': open error: Read-only file system [v8.24.0-57.el7_9.3 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2433 ]
Jan 20 19:34:36 server.mm.com rsyslogd[1205]: action 'action 0' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.24.0-57.el7_9.3 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Jan 20 19:34:36 server.mm.com rsyslogd[1205]: file '/var/log/messages': open error: Read-only file system [v8.24.0-57.el7_9.3 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2433 ]
Jan 20 19:34:36 server.mm.com rsyslogd[1205]: action 'action 0' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.24.0-57.el7_9.3 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Jan 20 19:34:36 server.mm.com rsyslogd[1205]: file '/var/log/messages': open error: Read-only file system [v8.24.0-57.el7_9.3 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2433 ]
Jan 20 19:34:36 server.mm.com rsyslogd[1205]: action 'action 0' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.24.0-57.el7_9.3 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Jan 20 19:34:36 server.mm.com rsyslogd[1205]: file '/var/log/messages': open error: Read-only file system [v8.24.0-57.el7_9.3 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2433 ]
Jan 20 19:34:36 server.mm.com rsyslogd[1205]: action 'action 0' suspended, next retry is Fri Jan 20 19:35:06 2023 [v8.24.0-57.el7_9.3 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Jan 20 19:34:36 server.mm.com rsyslogd[1205]: imjournal: fopen() failed for path: '/var/lib/rsyslog/imjournal.state.tmp': Read-only file system [v8.24.0-57.el7_9.3 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2013 ]
Jan 20 19:34:36 server.mm.com rsyslogd[1205]: imjournal: fopen() failed for path: '/var/lib/rsyslog/imjournal.state.tmp': Read-only file system [v8.24.0-57.el7_9.3 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2013 ]
Jan 20 19:34:36 server.mm.com rsyslogd[1205]: imjournal: fopen() failed for path: '/var/lib/rsyslog/imjournal.state.tmp': Read-only file system [v8.24.0-57.el7_9.3 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2013 ]
```

**Solved:**
I contacted Hetzner support, and they fixed it for me
appreciate!

```
Please use the following wiki guide to run the file system check:

-----------------%<-----------------
https://docs.hetzner.com/robot/dedicated-server/troubleshooting/filesystem-check/
```

Comment: Could you possibly include the actual error message you see when trying to open or save the file using `vim`, exactly as it is shown? It's currently unclear where the message in the title of your question comes from.

Comment: "/etc/fstab" E212: Can't open file for writing

Comment: @Kusalananda thank you for your comment I just edited the question and added the actual error

Comment: @kusalananda I added some details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if remount with rw permissions didn't work, try to boot the server in rescue mode and run a filesystem check(fsck) on the partition, and then try to remount it again. You can also try to repair the file system using the command e2fsck -p /dev/sda1 (assuming that /dev/sda1 is the partition that is having the problem).

Comment: devtmpfs         32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs            32G   25M   32G   1% /run
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md2        874G  545G  285G  66% /
tmpfs           6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/0

Comment: These are my partitions; what command should I use for repair?

Comment: /dev/md2 is your physical device, execute fsck on that one, but it is recommended to do it on rescue mode or from an external system like a live linux installer.